# python lxml get xpath of element with class/id names

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to extract the absolute xpath of an element with LXML. I'm using this source code to do so, but looks like the xpath doesn't contain any class name or ID name

```
import requests, lxml.html
url= "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath"
resp = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
a = tree.xpath('//a[@href]') 
for x in a :
    path = x.getroottree().getpath(x)
    print(path)
```

this code returns stuff like this :

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[12]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[4]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[12]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/ul/li[5]/a
...
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/nav[6]/div/ul/li[20]/a
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/nav[6]/div/div/span/a
...
/html/body/footer/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]
/html/body/footer/ul[1]/li[2]/a[2]
/html/body/footer/ul[1]/li[2]/a[3]
...
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[1]/a
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[2]/a
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[3]/a
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[4]/a
...
```

what I would like to get is the classname or ID when possible, like this :

```
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[@class='toclevel-2 tocsection-5'][3]/a
/html/body/footer/ul[2]/li[@class='toclevel-2 tocsection-5'][4]/a
```

any way to do so ?

Comment: Have you considered using BeautifulSoup to parse the html? - [https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: thanks @wwii yeah but BS is way slower than LXML

Comment: For one thing: There is no such thing as "the absolute XPath" - there are infinitely many XPaths that can lead to an element, and none of them is "the true one". And for another thing: What do you need the XPath *for*? Can you outline what you intend to do with the XPath expression eventually?

Comment: (Oh and BTW, consuming HTML might be less painful with [pyquery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/), which I think is a lot easier to handle and both more expressive and more familiar than bs4)

Comment: thanks @Tomalak for your reply. I wanted to classify links depending of their context (ex: links in header, sidebar, footer, on in text links). my though was to extract the abslute path and look if they contains ID/class describing every context (template vs in text)

Comment: But when you have all the links (i.e. the `<a>` element objects from the document tree), it's your could classify them by looping over them and looking at their parent nodes. You don't need to generate an XPath expression and *hope* that it contains something you can use.

Comment: Besides, creating an XPath from each node requires looking at all its parents and doing some processing for each parent, so "looking at each parent and doing some processing" is what you're doing *anyway*. Which means you're not losing any time by doing something other than "creating an XPath".

Comment: @Tomalak that's a good ideas, but it can't work out for me this way. I'm applying some rules from.a configuration file that says "links in the footer contains this classname or id". it can be the element it self or its parent or grand parent... that's why extracting the xpath and performing an "includes" logique is the easiest way to do so in my opinion (and maybe the most efficient too)?

Comment: Well if you know this stuff ahead of time, what's wrong with `//div[contains(@class, 'some-classname')]//a` to get all links beneath a div with a certain CSS class? You could build these kinds of expressions dynamically.

Comment: I'm with @Tomalak here. If clasification criterion is known in advance, it would be worth to try to express it in the XPath expression itself. If criterion is already well expressed in another artifact, it makes no sense to introduce XPath into the process.